# Real Convergence

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, bq, m10

Anybody knows which Ubuntu Touch version will be trully convergible?

I purchased a BQ M10 thinking use it to work but there's no VNC or RDP client. There's no File Manager with SSH support and none development tool or IDE.

In this time my Android smartphone seems to be most usable. What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is wrong... Ubuntu for phones is stable and usable, just it is not (yet?) for everybody and there is not yet everything :) Something is missing? You are welcome to develop it and publish it for the community! :D

Comment: I agree that Ubuntu Touch on the M10 is very incomplete at this point, but there is hope that it will improve a lot when OTA-11 becomes available at the end of the month, which should be based on Ubuntu 16.04 instead of 15.04. It should then be possible to easily install "legacy" applications inside of Libertine containers, so hopefully most software from the Ubuntu repositories will be available, and now that people are getting their hands on the M10 I expect "native" packages to become available also for tablet-specific software.

Comment: @dadexix86 I'm not a Linux developer. I didn't purchased it to developing Ubuntu Touch apps'.

Comment: @JensGrivolla Thanks for your reply. I'll put my hopes in futures updates. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to reply Vistaus.

I need to update this thread.

I got to run legacy apps using the Libertine emulador. It's preinstalled in Ubuntu Touch and it's responsable to run the preinstalled desktop apps LibreOffice, Gimp and Firefox.

Libertine emulator is still experimental and maybe that's the reason it is not accessable by default but it is working properly and there's some official documentation of how to implement it. Now I'm using Remmina to VNC/RDP remote access and another desktop applications on Ubuntu Touch.

Thank you Jens Grivolla! Without your comment I wouldn't know that Libertine exists.